# Como fazer gráfico dinâmico baseado em registros do banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, gráfico

O meu sistema tem uma página com uma tabela que mostra cada registro do banco com um botão para abrir um modal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que dentro desse modal tivesse um gráfico que comparasse a quantidade de ações previstas com a quantidade de ações realizadas mês a mês.

Porém, como eu só tenho um botão que se repete de acordo com a quantidade de registros dentro de um **while**, eu não sei como fazer pra esse botão entender qual é o **ID** do registro e gerar um gráfico dinamicamente pra ele.

**O código:**

```
<!-- Main -->
        <div class="content-lg container">
            <div class="row margin-b-20">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h2>Resultados</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 sm-margin-b-50">
                    <?php 
                            //Conexão e consulta ao Mysql
                            $lnk = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
                            mysqli_select_db($lnk,'banco') or die(mysql_error());
                            $qry = mysqli_query($lnk, "select * from gptw");

                            //Pegando os nomes dos campos
                            $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado

                            for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
                                $fields[] = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($qry,$i)->name;
                            }

                            //Montando o cabeçalho da tabela
                            $table = '<table class="table table-hover table-inverse"> <tr style="">';

                            for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
                                $table .= '<th>'.$fields[$i].'</th>';
                            }

                            //Montando o corpo da tabela
                            $table .= '<tbody >';
                            while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
                                $table .= '<tr>';
                                for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
                                    $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
                                }

                                // ADICIONANDO BOTÃO DE EDIÇÃO
                                $table .= '<td><form action="edicao-gptw.php" method="post">'; 
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN PREV" value="'.$r['JAN PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN REAL" value="'.$r['JAN REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="FEV PREV" value="'.$r['FEV PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="FEV REAL" value="'.$r['FEV REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAR PREV" value="'.$r['MAR PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAR REAL" value="'.$r['MAR REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ABR PREV" value="'.$r['ABR PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ABR REAL" value="'.$r['ABR REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAI PREV" value="'.$r['MAI PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAI REAL" value="'.$r['MAI REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUN PREV" value="'.$r['JUN PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUN REAL" value="'.$r['JUN REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUL PREV" value="'.$r['JUL PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUL REAL" value="'.$r['JUL REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="AGO PREV" value="'.$r['AGO PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="AGO REAL" value="'.$r['AGO REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="SET PREV" value="'.$r['SET PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="SET REAL" value="'.$r['SET REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="OUT PREV" value="'.$r['OUT PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="OUT REAL" value="'.$r['OUT REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="NOV PREV" value="'.$r['NOV PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="NOV REAL" value="'.$r['NOV REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ PREV" value="'.$r['DEZ PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ REAL" value="'.$r['DEZ REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></i> Editar </i></button>'; //
                                $table .= '</form></td>';


                                // ADICIONANDO MODAL PARA GRÁFICO
                                $table .= '<td><form action="graf-gptw.php" method="post">'; 
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN PREV" value="'.$r['JAN PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN REAL" value="'.$r['JAN REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="FEV PREV" value="'.$r['FEV PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="FEV REAL" value="'.$r['FEV REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAR PREV" value="'.$r['MAR PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAR REAL" value="'.$r['MAR REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ABR PREV" value="'.$r['ABR PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ABR REAL" value="'.$r['ABR REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAI PREV" value="'.$r['MAI PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAI REAL" value="'.$r['MAI REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUN PREV" value="'.$r['JUN PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUN REAL" value="'.$r['JUN REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUL PREV" value="'.$r['JUL PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUL REAL" value="'.$r['JUL REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="AGO PREV" value="'.$r['AGO PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="AGO REAL" value="'.$r['AGO REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="SET PREV" value="'.$r['SET PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="SET REAL" value="'.$r['SET REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="OUT PREV" value="'.$r['OUT PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="OUT REAL" value="'.$r['OUT REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="NOV PREV" value="'.$r['NOV PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="NOV REAL" value="'.$r['NOV REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ PREV" value="'.$r['DEZ PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ REAL" value="'.$r['DEZ REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<!-- Button -->
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                                              Gráfico
                                            </button>

                                            <!-- Modal -->
                                            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                  <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Gráfico</h5>
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                  </div>
                                                  <div class="modal-body">

                                                    Aqui entra o gráfico.


                                                  </div>
                                                  <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                  </div>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>'; //
                                $table .= '</form></td>';



                            }

                            //Finalizando a tabela
                            $table .= '</tbody></table>';

                            //Imprimindo a tabela
                            echo '<div class="table-table" style="overflow-x:auto;">';
                            echo $table;
                    ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <!--<img class="img-responsive" src="img/640x380/01.jpg" alt="Our Office">-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Eu até sei fazer um gráfico para cada registro do banco de dados em **php** e **highharts**, mas não sei fazer um gráfico só que se se adapta dependendo do registro que tenha sido clicado.

Alguém tem algum exemplo pra me dar um norte?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você já ouviu falar no C3? É uma biblioteca js de gráficos que é muito bonita e fácil de usar.

http://c3js.org/

Talvez possa te ajudar! Abraços

Comment: Então, eu uso o Highcharts pra gráficos em JS, eu só não sei como eu vou fazer ele dinamicamente se adequando ao registro clicado.